# Make things happen in certain time frame

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a program that after 4:00 am it says "good morning sir" and after 12:00 noon it says "good afternoon sir". (I'll add evening later i just want to get this nailed down first) I made an if statement to compare the times like this

```
DateTime t1 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime t2 = new DateTime(4);
DateTime t3 = new DateTime(12);
DateTime.Compare(t1, t2);
DateTime.Compare(t1, t3);
if (t1 >= t2)
{
    s.Speak("good morning sir");
}
if (t1 >= t3)
{                 
      s.Speak("good afternoon sir");
}
```

The problem is that when i run it, it says both good morning and good afternoon. How do i make it so it only says good morning after 4 am and good afternoon after 12 noon. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can add to your if statement to check if now is also less than noon, or you can use an else if but you will have to change the noon check to be first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just compare the `Hour` property of `DateTime.Now` with numbers instead of other `DateTime`s?

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
if (now.Hour >= 4 && now.Hour < 12) {
    Console.WriteLine("Good morning");
} else if (now.Hour >= 12) {
    Console.WriteLine("Good afternoon");
}
```

Your code is incorrect because the `DateTime` constructor that takes 1 argument will create a `DateTime` with that many *ticks*, not hours. To create a `DateTime` with a specific hour, you can use this constructor:

```
new DateTime(2018, 3, 8, 6, 45, 0);
                         ^
                         |
                       hour
```

If you are using NodaTime, you can create 2 `LocalTime` instances and compare them like this:

```
var now = SystemClock.Instance.Now.InZone(DateTimeZoneProviders.Bcl.GetSystemDefault()).TimeOfDay;
var four = new LocalTime(4, 0);
var noon = LocalTime.Noon;
if (now >= four && now < noon) {
    Console.WriteLine("Good morning");
} else if (now >= noon) {
    Console.WriteLine("Good afternoon");
}
```

Comment: Alright so i tried your first option but it only says "good morning." what do i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
if(DateTime.Now.Hour >= 4)
{
    ....
}
else if(DateTime.Now.Hour >= 12)
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually its better to compare hour when it comes to distinguish morning or afternoon:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/jcFN0c

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {   
        SayHello(DateTime.Now);
        SayHello(DateTime.Now.AddHours(6));
    }

    private static void SayHello(DateTime time)
    {
        if (time.Hour >= 4 && time.Hour < 12)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("good morning sir. It's {0} o'clock right now.", time));
        }
        else
        {                 
             Console.WriteLine(String.Format("good afternoon sir. It's {0} o'clock right now.", time));
        }       
    }

}
```